# Подгрузка блоков при скроллинге

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Реализовываю динамическую прогрузку контента при достижении футера. Костылями, без ajax. На странице 50 блоков. Каждому блоку присвоен rel. По номеру rel решаю сколько загружать блоков. В общем этот код, отрабатывает только лишь раз при достижении футера. Можно ли как то именно этот код заставить отрабатывать бесконечное число раз. Допустим прогружать по 10 блоков, пока не прогрузит все.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
 {
  c= $('a[rel]');  
  c.each(function() {
  max = 18;
  f= $(this).attr('rel');
  if (f < max){
  $(this).show();
} 
  }); 
}
});
```

Т.е. сейчас он прогружает 18 блоков и все, а должен по 18 каждый раз когда скролл достигает футера. Спасибо.

Comment: мне стало любопытно, вот, что у меня получилось https://jsfiddle.net/a3ccocav/

Comment: @splash58 ток задержку добавить в тестовом и анимацию загрузки))

Comment: @splash58 а ларчик просто открывался) Спасибо добрый человек! Все работает.